# Writing an $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proof of $\lim_{x\to a}[f(x)g(x)] = \infty$, given $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\infty$, $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=c>0$

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

This is problem 1.7 44b from *Calculus 7th Edition* by *James Stewart*. The problem asks me to write an $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proof on the limit
$$\lim_{x\to a}[f(x)g(x)] = \infty$$
Given that $$\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = \infty\qquad and\qquad \lim_{x\to a}g(x) = c\quad where\quad c > 0$$

---

My solution:

Suppose that

(1) for every $M_1>0$, there is a $\delta_1>0$ such that if $0<|x-a|<\delta_1$ then $f(x)>M_1$

(2) for every $\varepsilon>0$, there is $\delta_2>0$ such that if $0<|x-a|<\delta_1$ then $|g(x)-c|<\varepsilon$.

I want to show that for every $M_2>0$, there is $\delta_3>0$ such that if $0<|x-a|<\delta_3$ then $f(x)g(x) > M_2$.

To satisfy the two assumptions, I guess $\delta_3 = min(\delta_1,\delta_2)$.

Proof

Given a positive number $M_2$ I choose $\delta_3 = min(\delta_1,\delta_2)$, so that

(1) if $0<|x-a|<\delta_3$ then $f(x)>M_1$

(2) if $0<|x-a|<\delta_3$ then $|g(x)-c|<\varepsilon$ where $c>0$.

I then start by rearranging inequality (2).

$$-\varepsilon<g(x)-c<\varepsilon$$

$$-\varepsilon+c<g(x)<\varepsilon+c$$

Since $M_1>0$ and $f(x)>0$, then multiplying this with the inequality above gives

$$f(x)g(x) > M_1(-\varepsilon+c)$$

Now I know that to continue the proof, I must show that $M_1(-\varepsilon+c)$ is positive and it can be as large as one please; however, the problem is $(-\varepsilon+c)$ could be negative which makes $M_1(-\varepsilon+c)$ negative because $M_1>0$. I know that I must assume $0<\varepsilon<c$ but I don't see the reason why I can make such assumption since according to the definition, all $\varepsilon>0$ must work. Can anyone please explain why? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

$\epsilon$ is completely your choice. Your are given that $\lim_{x \to a} g(x) =c$ and you can apply the definition of limit here with any $\epsilon $ you like. So choose any $\epsilon \in (0,c)$, say $\epsilon =\frac c2$, and your proof works fine.

Comment: I am sorry to say I still can't understand why $\varepsilon$ is completely my choice. What if I choose an $\varepsilon$ that satisfy inequality (2) but make the $(-\varepsilon+c)$ negative? Shouldn't the inequality $f(x)g(x) > M_2$ be satisfied for any arbitrary value of $\varepsilon$ in order to prove the whole thing?

Comment: You are trying to prove that three exists $\delta >0$ such that  $f(x)g(x) >M$ for $|x-a| <\delta$. This statement does not involve any $\epsilon$. $\epsilon$ is just some positive number you introduce in the proof and that is why you are free to choose any $\epsilon>0$. @YongyuthaKunapinun

Comment: Now what I 'think' I understand is that since $\varepsilon$ can be any positive number, then there is always some $\varepsilon$ that make $M_1(-\varepsilon+c)$ positive. Although there are also some $\varepsilon$ that make $M_1(-\varepsilon+c)$ negative, I don't have to care about that case because all I need to show is that $M_1(-\varepsilon+c)$ could get positive large without bound. Is this the exact reason why I have the freedom to choose any value of $\varepsilon$?

Comment: @YongyuthaKunapinun: when you are given that a limit equation $\lim_{x\to a} g(x) =c$ holds then by definition you are given the truth of infinite number statements (one for each positive $\epsilon$). Here out of all those infinitely many true statements you are supposed to choose one which suits your purpose. For example choose the statement which is based on $\epsilon=c/2$ (you can choose any $\epsilon$ which makes $c-\epsilon >0$ because that is what you need here).

Comment: @YongyuthaKunapinun: the fact that a limit statements is equivalent to the truth of infinitely many statements is something which may seem difficult to handle but that is what makes it a powerful concept. Try to compare it with a statement like $a+ b=b+a$ which also implies the truth of infinitely many statements (one for each pair of numbers $a, b$) and try to figure out why the algebraic statement is easier to deal with than the limit statement.

Answer (score 2):

Take $\epsilon = \frac{ c}{2} >0 $, then $g(x) > c/2$ and if we choose $M_1 = 2M_2/c $, then We see that $f(x)g(x) > M_2$